# In python how do I create a variable number of Turtle clones in the Turtle module?

Tags: python, variables

I have tried to do a for loop to achieve a variable number of turtle clones but it doesn't create variables it only changes them.
This is what I have tried but it doesn't create 20 clones with their name being a number from 1-20.
The only reason that I want to do this is so I can easily create several turtles with easily accessible names:

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
turtle = Turtle()
for idx in range(20):
  idx = turtle.clone()
for turtle in turtles():
  print(turtle)
```

Comment: An Array structure, perhaps? Can't give you much actionable advice without seeing the code you're trying to run and getting stuck on. [ask]

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You might wanna look at basic data structures in Python. @COLE

Comment: I see you have improved your question, but you should look up the linked question. This will show you a number of ways to achieve what you want. You could start with this: `turtles = [Turtle() for _ in range(20)]`

Comment: I tried doing the: `turtles = [Turtle() for _ in range(20)]`  and I get the error that says that "turtles" is a list and I need clones if that makes sense.